# Selenium cannot find div inputfield element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web

```
<div class="writtingArea _editor" contenteditable="true" placeholder="보낼 메시지를 입력하세요."></div>
```

it is element that i needed to find and send chat but if i try to find this with this line of code,

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("writtingArea _editor").click()
```

it gives me error that says it couldn't locate element. So i tried to locate it by Xpath. but it didn't work either.

How can i fix this??

Comment: Can you show what you tried for xpath?

Comment: Please provide complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is a space between two class names you are not able to call that class names merged.

Please try below line to find and click that element.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.writtingArea._editor").click()
```